# Unexpected destructor call occurs when paired with move constuctor

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, move-semantics

The following code was compiled and run in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop, as a learning exercise.

```
#include <cstdio>

class X
{
public:
    X()  { printf("default constructed\n"); }
    ~X() { printf("destructed\n");}
    X(const X&) { printf("copy constructed\n"); }
    X(X&&) { printf("move constructed\n"); }
    X & operator= (const X &) { printf("copy assignment operator\n"); }
};

X A() {
    X x;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    {
        A();
    }
    std::getchar();
}
```

When compiled with compiler optimizations disabled (/Od), the resulting output indicates that the destructor is called twice. This is a problem given that only one object is constructed. **Why is the destructor being called twice?** Wouldn't this be a problem if the class was managing it own resources?

```
default constructed
move constructed
destructed
destructed   <<< Unexpected call
```

I tried a couple of experiments to try and explain the output, but ultimately these didn't lead to any useful explanations.

Experiment 1: When the same code is compiled with optimizations enabled (/O1 or /O2), the resulting output is:

```
default constructed
destructed
```

which indicates that the Named Return Value Optimization has elided the call to the move constructor, and masked the underlying problem.

Experiment 2: Disabled the optimization and commented out the move constructor. The output generated was what I expected.

```
default constructed
copy constructed
destructed
destructed
```

Comment: You have the same number of constructors as destructors, so there's no problem.  The fact that it was moved form is not relevant.  This is not a problem for classes that manage resources, they all work with the understanding that this is how things work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Michael's and jspcal answers are accurate, they didn't answer the heart of my question, which was why were there two destructor calls made. I was expecting just one.

The answer is that function A() returns a temporary object. Always. This is how function return values work, and move-semantics has no bearing on this fact. I guess Michael and jspcal assumed that I had not missed such a basic fact. I equated the term "moved" with the concept of "swap". When swapped, objects are not constructed and destructed. Hence I was expecting just one destructor call.

Since the returned object must be constructed and destructed, the second destructor call was made (and a second constructor call).

Now, the actual constructor selected to be executed depends on what is provided in the class definition. If a move-constructor is available, that will be called. Otherwise the copy constructor will be called.

Answer (score 7):

Keep in mind that when an object is the source of a move operation it will still be destroyed.  So the source of the move needs to put itself in a state such that being destructed will not release resources that it no longer owns (since they were moved to another object).  For example, any raw pointers (that will now be owned by the move constructed object) in the source object should be set to NULL.

Answer (score 3):

The X in A is destroyed when it goes out of scope.

A returns a temporary object (constructed from X by the move constructor) which is a separate instance. This is destroyed in the caller's scope. That will cause the destructor to be called again (on the temporary).

The move constructor was picked because the compiler detected that X was going to be destroyed immediately afterward. To use this approach, the move constructor should nullify or reset any data in the original object so that the destructor will not invalidate any data that has been taken over by the destination of the move.

> When you pass an rvalue by value, or return anything by value from a function, the compiler first gets the option to elide the copy. If the copy isn’t elided, but the type in question has a move constructor, the compiler is required to use the move constructor.

http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/09/move-it-with-rvalue-references/

> When you exit from the scope in which the temporary object was created, it is destroyed. If a reference is bound to a temporary object, the temporary object is destroyed when the reference passes out of scope unless it is destroyed earlier by a break in the flow of control.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr382.htm

The RVO can produce different behavior from the non-optimized version:

> Return value optimization, or simply RVO, is a compiler optimization technique that involves eliminating the temporary object created to hold a function's return value.[1] In C++, it is particularly notable for being allowed to change the observable behaviour of the resulting program.[2]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Comment: To clarify, which constructor is being used to create the temporary object?

Comment: you are correct, but why the constructor is not being called for temporary object?

Comment: The move constructor initializes the temporary object, so the default ctor is not called in that case.